# Toggling Logo Image on Menu Button Click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'd like to change the colour of my logo when the menu button is clicked to match the style of the overlay.

Currently, I've been able to change it from black logo to white logo. However, when you attempt to close the menu, it does not change back to black logo, even though my js function should handle the switch.

Any help is appreciated.

```js
function menuButton(x) {
  x.classList.toggle("change");
}

function toggleNav() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myNav");
  if (x.style.height === "100%") {
    x.style.height = "0%";
  } else {
    x.style.height = "100%";
  }
}

function changeImg() {
  var logo = document.getElementById("logo");
  if (logo.src == "/images/1x/White.png") {
    logo.src = "/images/1x/Asset 1.png";
  } else {
    logo.src = "/images/1x/White.png";
  }
}
```

```css
/* Global */

.white {
  color: #fff
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  /* background-color: darkgray; */
}


/* Header */

header {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 80px;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  position: fixed;
  margin: 0px;
  /* border-bottom: 5px solid black; */
  /* z-index: 2; */
}

.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

header .logo {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 4px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

header .menu {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}


/* header .title h1{
        margin: 21.5px 0px 0px 0px;
        padding: 0;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
        font-size: 30px;
    }
    
    header .title a:link, a:visited{
        color: black;
        text-decoration: none;
    } */

.bar1,
.bar2,
.bar3 {
  background-color: black;
  width: 35px;
  height: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.change .bar1 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
  background-color: white;
}

.change .bar2 {
  opacity: 0;
}

.change .bar3 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
  background-color: white;
}


/* Navigation */

.overlay {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  z-index: 0;
  transition: 0.5s;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.overlayContent {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  top: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-top: 30px;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}

.overlay a {
  padding: 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 36px;
  color: whitesmoke;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.overlay a:hover,
a:active {
  color: darkgrey;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Header Start - Includes Title, Logo, and Menu -->
<header id="top">

  <div class="container">

    <!-- Logo -->
    <div class="logo">
      <a href="#top" class="logo"><img id="logo" src="/images/1x/Asset 1.png" alt="Initials JB"></a>
    </div>

    <!-- Menu Button -->
    <div class='menu' onclick="menuButton(this); toggleNav(); changeImg()">
      <div class="bar1"></div>
      <div class="bar2"></div>
      <div class="bar3"></div>
    </div>

    <!-- Title -->
    <!-- <div class = "title">
                    <h1>
                        <a href="#top">JADON BULL</a>
                    </h1>
                </div> -->

    <!-- Navigation Start -->
    <div class="container">
      <nav id="myNav" class="overlay">
        <div class="overlayContent">
          <a href="#">Overview</a>
          <a href="#">Projects</a>
          <a href="#">Services</a>
          <a href="#">About Me</a>
          <a href="#">Contact</a>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
<!-- Header End -->

<!-- Showcase -->
<div id="showcase">

</div>






JS:
```

[image: Black Logo]

[image: White Logo]

Comment: Hi Jadon Bull. Make sure your `path` (relative or absolute) is correct. Just give a try to `./images/1x/Asset 1.png`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use absolute path of the image to the source of the image.

in the `changeImg` function, just change your `if` condition to :

```
if (logo.getAttribute('src') === '/images/1x/White.png')
```

and it will work.

Comment: Thanks Suhas, this worked! Could you help me understand exactly how this works? And when to use logo.getAttribute('src') vs. just logo.src?

Comment: @JadonBull when you want the location of your file from the root directory, use the `.src` and when you want to use the path from the current working directory, use `.getAttribute()`.

Answer (score 2):

There is a small error in your below line:

```
logo.src = "/images/1x/Asset 1.png";
```

Always make sure any filename or asset do not have spaces in their name. You could use underscore Asset_1.png and save the image. Later, use it as

```
logo.src = "/images/1x/Asset_1.png";
```

Also change the name if used elsewhere in html or css.